# loop through Get-Process results in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, pid

The following one-line code should resize all open windows by gathering their pid and passing them to [Set-Window](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Set-the-position-and-size-54853527) ([updated](https://superuser.com/a/1324170)) script.

```
Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -ne ""} | ForEach-Object {Set-Window -Id $_.ID -X 0 -Y 0 -Height 500 - Width 500}
```

but I get the following error:

```
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Window], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Set-Window
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Please add the specific error to the question.

Comment: You have a space between `- Width` which causes several positional parameters rather then a named `-Witch` parameter.